# I am trying to fetch master account field on controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity

I am able to get Account Id from opportunity controller but i need to fetch Customer_Group_Trio__c(picklist) account field from that id. It is throwing error. please help

```
public class CreateOppExtension 
{
    Opportunity opp{set;get;}
     public string Customergrp; 


    public CreateOppExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
      {   
          opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();

         opp.AccountId =apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('AccountId');
         opp.Master_Account__c=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('AccountId');
        Customergrp = [select Customer_Group_Trio__c from Account where id =opp.AccountId] ;
 }
```

I am getting errors unexpected token: 'opp.AccountId'  expecting a colon, found 'opp.AccountId'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to add **colon ":"**  before opp.AccountId,

and also your assigning Object to a String.

Change the statement as below

```
Customergrp = [select Customer_Group_Trio__c from Account where id = :opp.AccountId limit 1].Customer_Group_Trio__c;
```

**or**

```
Account acc= [select Customer_Group_Trio__c from Account where id = :opp.AccountId limit 1] ;

Customergrp =acc.Customer_Group_Trio__c;
```

Comment: I tried this Customergrp = [select Customer_Group_Trio__c from Account where id = :opp.AccountId] ;                                                                        .. It is throwing error illegal assignment from list to string error.  But why should i intialize Customergrp to overcome that error? I just need one picklist value (string) from single id.

Comment: Find updated code

Comment: Thank you so much Nitesh K for helping every time :) Appreciate it!

Comment: Your welcome.. if it is working don't forget vote please..